# Python: [WinError 32] issue

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to copy each line of a text file into a new one, unless the line is a specially designated one, in which case it will change part of that line and then save the line like normal to the new file.

I'm asking this because I tried using the fixes given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747577/python-why-am-i-getting-a-winerror-32), but I'm still getting the same error.

To answer potential questions:

- I have a file named 'save.txt' that is being renamed to 'oldsave.txt' in order to create a new file named 'save.txt'.
- 'rN' is just a integer value generated by another function.
- All the libraries I need have been imported before the function is called

Here's the function:

```
os.rename(file1,'oldsave.txt') 
oldSave = open(file1)
newSave = open('save.txt','a')

count = 1
for line in oldSave:    
    if count != rN: 
        newSave.write(line)
    else:
        chosen_album = []
        line = line.strip()
        chosen_album.append(line.split('|'))
        chosen_album[4] += 1
        newSave.write(chosen_album)
    count += 1
oldSave.close()
newSave.close()
os.rename('newsave.txt','save.txt')
os.remove('oldsave.txt')
```

This is the error I get when I run it:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'oldsave.txt'
```

As far as I know, the issue lies in the opening/closing/renaming of the files.

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? I can't tell if the problem is in the beginning or the end of your script

Comment: It's in lines 2-3, as listed in the code block above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, `file1` **is** `'save.txt'` so...

```
oldSave = open(file1)
newSave = open('save.txt','a')
```

means you're trying to do:

```
oldSave = open('save.txt')
newSave = open('save.txt','a')
```

Which I believe isn't what you want. What you *are* trying to do is:

```
oldSave = open('oldsave.txt')
newSave = open('save.txt','a')
```

(I hardcoded the strings. Use whichever variables are appropriate to your program)

Comment: I implemented your fix, and it looks like I'm no longer receiving that error. Thanks a lot!